# Moving elements in an array by certain amount

Tags: c++, arrays, encryption, shift

So I have a program that reads in a certain number of keys. An example would be

```
5 1 10 21 9 6 21 11 13 16 20
```

The text file example would be

```
Java 2 linux 3 fear 0 pool 2 do 0 red 1 lock. 1 I 0 random 2
```

I want my program to start at Java and depending on first key, which in this case is 5, would move over 5 elements leading to "red". And so on and so on. However, I have managed to read in all the data and put them into arrays, I am just having trouble figuring out how to move the pointer in the array.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct pieces {

char word[5];
int jump;
} ;

 // Main Function
int main ()
{
// declare variables
int wordCount[2];
int keyCount[2];
int numKeys, numKeys2;
int numWords;
int keyAmount = 1;
int wordAmount = 23;
int keyarr[11];
pieces cypher[wordAmount];
char filename[10];
ifstream inData;
int temp[10];

  //prompt user for input file

cout << " Enter file name: ";
cin >> filename;

inData.open(filename);

if(inData.is_open());
{

    // read in data

for ( numKeys = numWords = 0; numKeys < keyAmount; numKeys++){

// read in num of words and keys
inData >> wordCount[numKeys] >> keyCount[numKeys];

        //read in words followed by jump key
        for( numWords = 0; numWords < wordAmount; numWords++){

        inData >> cypher[numWords].word >> cypher[numWords].jump;

        }

    // read in the actual keys
    for( numKeys2 = 0; numKeys2 < wordCount[numKeys]; numKeys2++){

    inData >> keyarr[numKeys2];

    }

}


//print out data

for( int j = 0; j < numKeys; j++){

cout << wordCount[j] << "\n";
cout << keyCount[j] << "\n";

}

cout << "\n";

for ( int i = 0; i < wordAmount; ++i){
cout << cypher[i].word << " ";
cout << cypher[i].jump << " ";

}

cout << "\nKeys: " << "\n";

for(int k = 0; k < 11; k++){

cout << keyarr[k] << " ";

}
cout << "\n";

}

inData.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be much easier if you used a `std::vector` instead of an array. It has operations to insert and remove elements, and it will automatically shift everything around them.

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately I am only allowed to use these header files.

Comment: It sure would be nice if people would say whether they're trying to implement something in the real world or they're doing homework with restrictions. It's not always obvious.